# Programmatically "strip" a PNG of unneeded information in Swift

Tags: swift, image

Is there a way to programmatically "strip" a PNG of unneeded information?

ImageMagick has a way to:

> Strip the image of any profiles, comments or these PNG chunks:
> bKGD,cHRM,EXIF,gAMA,iCCP,iTXt,sRGB,tEXt,zCCP,zTXt,date. To remove the
> orientation chunk, orNT, set the orientation to undefined, e.g.,
> -orient Undefined.

using the [-strip](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip) command seems to work for me and I am looking to programatically do this in Swift.

I have looked in packages like [swift-png](https://github.com/tayloraswift/swift-png/tree/master) but have not found anything.

Comment: I don't know a lot about the PNG format, but perhaps you can decode and then encode the png using swift-png? I think you wouldn't get any metadata like that in the decoded data.

Comment: The chunks are well defined https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG and all have a length at the start of the chunk so it's simple enough to skip over any you don't want and lay the remining chunks down in the original order in a new file. Stick to removing ancillary chunks - i.e. those beginning with a lower case letter.

Comment: Note that `pngcheck` is pretty good at disclosing the layout and offsets of chunks in PNG images.